# Difference between using Dto projection in JPA and setting transactional readOnly true that both prevent dirty check?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

As far as I khow, using `JPA Dto projection` prevent dirty check. On the other hand using `@Transactional(readonly=true)` also avoid dirty check. Now the question is that, What is diffrences and can/should be used along with each other?

What is the performance issue while using JPA Dto projection without @Transactional(readonly=true)?

Answer (score 1):

With @Transactional (readonly=true),

If this is the option, since the spring framework sets the hibernate session flush mode to MANUAL, no flush occurs unless a flush is called by force, so CUD operation does not work, and snapshots are saved as mentioned earlier. The performance is improved by not performing tasks such as change detection.

In addition, if the DB is divided into master and slave, if there is Read Only, the slave is called only for read. That is, the load of the DB server may be reduced depending on the situation.

If there is a corresponding annotation, we expect that the method will only perform actions for READ and it will be done. Here, when I work in object orientation, it came to mind to ensure the reliability of the object by placing a final if possible. And since I felt this point was important, I think I will explicitly keep using it even if I don't have any performance advantages in the option.

Comment: Thanks. And what about dto projection using only? Does it perform dirty check or not?

Comment: What happens on performance when using read only with entity And read only with dto ?